# CSS Positioning an image

Tags: html, css

Can someone plz show me how to center this image in its div while keeping the image overlapping its div top.

[jsfiddle.net/MalcollmS/0ees82hc](http://jsfiddle.net/MalcollmS/0ees82hc/)

```
<body>
    <div id="outerdiv">
        <div id="innerdiv">
            <img src="http://www.mylester.lester.com.au/Content/Images/LesterBanner.jpg" alt="lesterbanner" id="banner" />
            <div id="body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

body{
   height:100%;
    background-color: #142758;
    padding-top:50px;
}

#outerdiv {
    margin:auto;
    width:70%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#778CAC;
}
#innerdiv {
    width:95%;
    margin:auto;
    height:95%;
    background-color:white;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);

}
header {
    width:100%;
}
#banner {
    background-image:url('lesterbanner.jpg');
    width:300px;
    margin-left:auto;    
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:-90px;
}
```

Malcolm

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0ees82hc/1/?

Comment: Thanks...simple hey...i missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `text-align:center;` add to `#innerdiv`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0ees82hc/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

`img` tags are `display: inline-block` by default which can be centered with `text-align: center;` on the parent element:

```
#innerdiv {
  ...
  text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0ees82hc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using % for margin or assign it to a div here

```
<body>
<div id="outerdiv">
<div id="innerdiv">
<!-- assign div --><div class="img_holder">
<img src="http://www.mylester.lester.com.au/Content/Images/LesterBanner.jpg" alt="lesterbanner" id="banner" />
</div>
<div id="body">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Css

```
    body{
   height:100%;
    background-color: #142758;
    padding-top:50px;
}

#outerdiv {
    margin:auto;
    width:70%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#778CAC;
}
#innerdiv {
    width:95%;
    margin:auto;
    height:95%;
    background-color:white;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);

}
header {
    width:100%;
}
#banner {
    background-image:url('lesterbanner.jpg');
    width:100%;
}
.img_holder{
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#banner {
    background-image:url('lesterbanner.jpg');
    width:300px;
    margin:-2% 0 0 42%;
}
```